# Using mahout's classifier in my web application

Tags: java, mahout, bayesian

I have developed a bayesian classifier using apache mahout. Now I would like to integrate it with my Java based web application, that is given a training model, the web app should be able to predict and classify the given text. It is a JSP based web app.

How should I go about it? Are there any blogs/sites that give a step by step tutorial to the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into source code of  News20Group example which will help you integrate mahout classifier with your webapp.

Also you can look source code of

```
org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.[TestClassifier][1]
org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.[TrainClassifier][2]
```